# Can't access docker containers from host

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, portforwarding

I have a simple image for a Rails service with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.4.4
MAINTAINER sadzid.suljic@gmail.com

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    nodejs

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN gem install bundler && bundle install

COPY . ./

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["rails", "s", "-p", "3000"]
```

I built the image and ran the container with these commands:

```
docker build -t chat/users .
docker run -P --name users_service chat/users
```

I have this output on the host:

```
 $ docker ps
 CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
 23716591e656        chat/users          "rails s -p 3000"   6 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:32774->3000/tcp   users_service

$ lsof -n -i :32774 | grep LISTEN
com.docke 32891 ssuljic   18u  IPv4 0x41c034d5d4627f5f      0t0  TCP *:filenet-re (LISTEN)
com.docke 32891 ssuljic   19u  IPv6 0x41c034d5d3beb9b7      0t0  TCP [::1]:filenet-re (LISTEN)

$ curl localhost:32774
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

When I run `curl localhost:3000` inside the container I get the proper response from my API.

Does anyone know why I can't access the container from my host?

I'm using Docker for Mac with this version:

```
$ docker -v
Docker version 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40
```

Comment: seems easy https://shivab.com/blog/docker/2019/01/15/dockerization-of-rails-6-app/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some versions of Rails bind to localhost by default, which explains why you can access from within the container but not from the host (it’s viewed as a different host).

Adding `-b 0.0.0.0` to the `CMD` instruction should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 --name users_service chat/users
```

This will map 3000 to 3000

```
http://localhost:3000
```

Looking into this more I think this was either and chrome issue or network issue as I was having the same issue:

Here is how I resolved it:

1. Make sure your `/etc/hosts` file has `127.0.0.1 localhost` (more than likely it's already there)
2. Cleared Cookies and Cached files
3. Cleared host cache

   Go to:`chrome://net-internals/#dns` click Clear Host Cache
4. Restarted chrome
5. Reset Network Adapter
   **Note:** *This was unintentional so not sure if it was part of the fix or not, but wanted to include it in case.*

Unfortunately I'm not sure which step fixed the problem

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I get the same error `curl: (52) Empty reply from server` when running `curl localhost:3000` on the host.

Comment: Just realized I mixed up 2 different but very similar questions I was looking into. However, this answer worked for the same issue,  although, the other issue was in a node/express app